# I m trying to use a "if" statement but it doesnt run

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, variables

[image]
I have this components

[image]
and i have this code as the if sentence.

I have the same method in other project that works, can anyone help?

[image]
it should only render the first one as addnewchat hte others ones should be avatars, if i take of the "!" only renders the avatars.

Comment: could you post your code as formatted text instead of images?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SidebarChat({ id, name, addNewChat }) like this works fine!
```

previously i had left a part the {} so that was the thing it was missing

Answer (score 0):

You can change the syntax of if and else. Instead of using ternary operator directly after return keyword, use a parent tag, and then wrap your whole component inside it. Like

```
return (
<>
  {addNewChat ? (
   <div>if logic here</div>
    ) : (
   <div>else logic here</div>
  )}
</>
)
```

Comment: I ve done what u said, but sitll not working

Answer (score 0):

calling component:

```
<div className="sidebar__chats">
        <SidebarChat addNewChat />
        <SidebarChat />
        <SidebarChat />
        <SidebarChat />
        <SidebarChat />
      </div>
```

code:

```
return (
    <>
      {addNewChat ? (
        <div className="sidebarChat">
          <Avatar
            alt="João Espinheira"
            src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/pixel-art/${seed}.svg`}
            sx={{ width: 38, height: 38 }}
          />
          <div className="sidebarChat__info">
            <h2>room name</h2>
            <p>last message...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div onClick={createChat} className="sidebarChat">
          <h2>add new chat</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

i think the code should work, no?